# Data not passing from main VC to embedded VC via prepareForSegue

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to pass data from the main VC (called StartVC) to an embedded VC (called MPList - which itself contains a tableview).

The solutions I have found all point to using the prepareforsegue method but this does not seem to work for me. The app runs with no errors and the tableview is not getting populated with the data I send.

In StartVC, I have implemented the prepareforsegue method as follows (In the attributes inspector, the embed segue definitely has an identifier of "LeftPane".):

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "LeftPane"{
        let mpListVC = segue.destination as? MPList
        mpListVC?.mpNames = self.mpNames

    }
}
```

mpNames is a string array initialised in the embedded MPList as follows (mpListTV is the IBOUTLET for the tableview in question):

```
class MPList: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


var mpNames = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    mpListTV.delegate = self
    mpListTV.dataSource = self


    print("names in MPList is: \(mpNames)")


}
```

The usual tableview control methods are implemented in MPList as well (and this is where mpNames is used too.):

```
    //MARK: - TABLEVIEW METHODS

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return mpNames.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = mpNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}
```

I have also made sure to right click and drag from the tableview to the little yellow icon at the top of the MPList viewcontroller and set both datasource and delegate.

I might just be tired (and missing something really obvious) after being at this for several hours now, but could someone please put me out of my misery and tell me what I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problems I see here:

### 1.

```
//in prepareForSegue
let mpListVC = segue.destination as? MPList
```

Make sure that the destination view controller in the IB **is indeed** set to `MPList`. Maybe `mpListVC` is `nil` here because of that. Just debug and make sure that `mpListVc` is not nil.

Also debug and **make sure** that no optional is nil. Better yet use force unwrapping (`!`) to try and find a possible `nil` somewhere.

Just set a breakpoint and check if `mpNames` is indeed set.

### 2.

`viewDidLoad` of `MPList` might be called before `prepareForSegue` for some reason, although it shouldn't. Either way it's a good practice to `reloadData` of the `UITableView` after resetting the array.

```
 var mpNames = [String]() {
    didSet {
       mpListView?.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Michal - Thanks for the reply! Option 2 solved my problem! I tried using the reloadData method in both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear of MPList but that did not work. Your solution worked like a charm! Thank you!